# angularJS binding not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, binding, angularjs, pug

I have a problem with Angular and Jade. I have my index.jade that it looks like this:

```
extends ../layouts/default

block content
  script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/angular.js')
  script(type='text/javascript', src='./controllers.js')

  ul(ng-controller='PhoneListCtrl')
    li(ng-repeat='phone in phones')
      {{phone.name}}
      p {{phone.snippet}}
```

and my angular controller which looks like this:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

function PhoneListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {"name": "Nexus S",
     "snippet": "Fast just got faster with Nexus S.",
     "age": 0},
    {"name": "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi",
     "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet.",
     "age": 2},
    {"name": "MOTOROLA XOOM™",
     "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet.",
     "age": 1}
  ];
}
```

And my problem is when I run the code the bindings in the index.jade don't work. So i'm kind of lost because I don't know why. Thanks for your help

Comment: The markup ng-app is in my layouts/default I tested and it works with a simple two-way binding data with an input. But when I decided to add the scope Phones the binding doesn't work

Comment: Try moving the `script` part of the code in the template to the bottom of the template - that is move the code such that it is the last code in the template. Check if this works.